# Test does not load many to many fixture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures

I am using Test to test my application. I have some fixtures: users.yml, roles.yml, roles_users.yml. The users and roles are loaded but not the many to many table roles_users so the users are not related to any role. With Rails console in development everything is ok, in test any user is not connected to any role. I can see the users and roles in the test database but roles_users is empty

Do I have to specify somewhere how to load this fixture?

Comment: Can you show us your test code and your fixtures?

Comment: I am able to load the fixture with this command RAILS_ENV=test rake db:fixtures:load FIXTURES=roles_users

This blog post has nice fixtures tips: http://techpolesen.blogspot.com/2007/04/rails-fixture-tips.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Rails >=2.2 and a standard HABTM association between users and roles, you shouldn't need the `roles_users.yml` file. Instead, add a `roles` line for each user in `users.yml`:

```
sally:
  roles: admin, editor
  ...

fred:
  roles: basic
  ...
```

The values are the names of your role fixtures. I'm not completely sure this will solve your problem, but it's cleaner at the very least.

Comment: Yes, Rails 2.4 is not loading the HABTM. However I was able to force that behaviour in my environment.rb using;

ENV['FIXTURES'] ||= 'roles_users'

Comment: When using your solution the roles_users table instead of having:
user_id = 1, role_id = 1
has:
user_id = 1232342, role_id = 1
Why user_id has that weired id?
The test fails because role_id 1 in not connected to user_id 1

Comment: When using fixtures in Rails, the accepted practice is to NOT assign an explicit ID to each object, but let Rails do it for you. It will base the ID on the name of the fixture so you can load a fixture by name in a test (eg: `users(:fred)`, or `roles(:admin)`). You will end up with some long numbers for IDs, but you never have to know them--you can use fixture names instead of IDs in your tests, which makes them easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Alex, another guy said that and I was the main problem. They told me to use factory_girl